# How to initialize a session in Catalyst application?

Tags: perl, catalyst

here is the myapp's module from the lib folder:

```
package myapp;
use Moose;
use namespace::autoclean;
use Catalyst::Runtime 5.80;
use Catalyst qw/
    ConfigLoader
    Session
    Session::Store
    Session::State
    Static::Simple
/;

extends 'Catalyst';
our $VERSION = '0.01';

__PACKAGE__->config(
    name => 'myapp',
    # Disable deprecated behavior needed by old applications
    disable_component_resolution_regex_fallback => 1,
    enable_catalyst_header => 1, # Send X-Catalyst header
);

sub init {
    my ( $c ) = @_;
    my ($sec,$min,$hour,$mday,$mon,$year,$wday,$yday,$isdst) = localtime();
    $c->session->{ed_year} = $year + 1900;
}

# Start the application
__PACKAGE__->setup();
__PACKAGE__->init();

1;
```

The example above is wrong, there is no available context($c). I would like to know if it is possible to initialize a session in a Catalyst application right in its main module. Here I would like to initialize global variables, used later by views, models and controllers?

Best regards,
SK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A session is associated with a user, and is an artifact of interaction with that user. You can't create a session in the main program - as you rightly say, there's no context at that point. In any case, what I think you're wanting to do is to configure some variables that will be available to any user of the application, so they're global, not user-specific anyway.

Use `__PACKAGE__->config` - it's just a hashref, and that's what it's for. You're certainly not limited to the documented keys.

For example:

```
__PACKAGE__->config(
    name => 'myapp',
    # Disable deprecated behavior needed by old applications
    disable_component_resolution_regex_fallback => 1,
    enable_catalyst_header => 1, # Send X-Catalyst header
    ed_year => (localtime())[5] + 1900,
    foo => { bar => 1, baz => 'quux' },
);
```

In your models, views and controllers those values will be available as `$c->config->{ed_year}` and `$c->config->{foo}->{baz}` and so on.

By the way, perhaps your use of `ed_year` was just a simplistic example, but consider how that will be instantiated: it will be the date and time the server is started, not the time of the current request. If the latter is what you want, put it in the `auto` handler of your `Root.pm` controller. And don't roll your own with `localtime`, use the `DateTime` module.